# Alignment problem: how do I find the minimum overall distance between two sets of points?

Tags: clojure, alignment

Given two sets, say N and M with n and m number of points respectively (each described with x and y coordinates), how do I find the best alignment of min(n,m) points so that I minimise the sum of euclidean distances of the aligned points?

I am trying to avoid the brute force method where I compare each possible combination of points from N and M.

I read up on it and the [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Solution_by_linear_programming) and it seems that I can define it as a Linear Program to solve it. However, I'm not sure how I would be able to write a program (e.g. in Clojure) to solve this problem. Is this the most optimal way?

Edit3: Added a new example: While the provided solution to @Rulle seems to work for the above example, it doesn't work for the following:

```
(def sample-set-a #{[0.575 0.675] [0.575 0.575]}) 

(def sample-set-b #{[0.575 0.675] [0.575 9.575]})
```

Which should give

`[ [0.575 0.675] [0.575 0.675], [0.575 0.575][0.575 9.575] ]`

Despite there being two possible solutions with the same weight:

`[  [0.575 0.575] [0.575 0.675],  [0.575 0.675] [0.575 9.575] ]`

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Can you please provide the equation of the objective function you are trying to minimize, or alternatively some sample input data and expected output data? If you provide the objective function, you can express it in Clojure code.

Comment: Please provide an example problem.  Don't ask people to guess about what you need.

Comment: Sorry, yes @Rulle has given a good example. I will include it in the original question.

Comment: Regarding with the last example of two solutions having the same weight, that is coherent with how you worded your original question. Please see my extended answer for how you can make the assignment prefer the exact match.

Comment: Sorry I didn't consider this case when posing my initial question. Thanks so much for addressing it too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly what you are trying to accomplish, suppose you have some points

```
(def sample-set-a #{[0 0] [1 0] [2 0] [0 1]})
```

and some other points

```
(def sample-set-b #{[1.1 -0.2] [0.01 0.99]})
```

you want to establish pairs between the elements of the first and the second set so that each point in the set with the least amount of points is matched with a unique point from the other set. With the above sample input, we would expect the result:

```
#{[[1 0] [1.1 -0.2]] [[0 1] [0.01 0.99]]}
```

There is a Clojure library for that [here](https://github.com/timothypratley/munkres). You can add the dependency `[munkres "0.5.0"]` to your `project.clj` file and then you just use that library. Here is an implementation of your problem using that library:

```
(ns assignment-problem.core
  (:require [munkres]))

(defn sqr [x]
  (* x x))

(defn dist [[x0 x1] [y0 y1]]
  (Math/sqrt (+ (sqr (- x0 y0))
                (sqr (- x1 y1)))))

(defn solve-euclidean-assignment [a b]
  (if (< (count b) (count a))
    (update (solve-euclidean-assignment b a) :assignments (partial mapv (comp vec reverse))) 
    (let [a (vec a)
          b (vec b)
          cost-matrix (for [x a]
                        (for [y b]
                          (dist x y)))]
      (munkres/minimize-weight cost-matrix a b))))
```

The function `solve-euclidean-assignment` is called with the two point sets, and then returns a map with keys `:assignments` and `:weight`, where `:assignments` contains the pairs. Here is an example of calling it:

```
(def sample-set-a #{[0 0] [1 0] [2 0] [0 1]})
(def sample-set-b #{[1.1 -0.2] [0.01 0.99]})
(solve-euclidean-assignment sample-set-a sample-set-b)
;; => {:assignments [[[1 0] [1.1 -0.2]] [[0 1] [0.01 0.99]]], :weight 0.23774893337370998}
```

**EXTENDED ANSWER: Other objective functions**

The above solution minimizes the objective function as stated in the original problem: *"minimise the sum of euclidean distances"*

However, this may not always lead to desired outcome, for example in the special case of

```
(def sample-set-a #{[0.575 0.675] [0.575 0.575]}) 
(def sample-set-b #{[0.575 0.675] [0.575 9.575]})
```

there are two possible solutions with the same minimized distance. In order to prefer the one with an exact match, we have to tweak the *objective function*. We rename `dist` to `euclidean-dist` and then we raise it to a power. A fractional power *less than 1* will tend to prefer solutions with exact matches:

```
(defn euclidean-dist [[x0 x1] [y0 y1]]
  (Math/sqrt (+ (sqr (- x0 y0))
                (sqr (- x1 y1)))))

(defn dist [a b]
  (let [e 0.5] ;; <-- A value less than 1 means we prefer exact matches. 
               ;; Raising to ½ is the same as computing the square root.
    (Math/pow (euclidean-dist a b) e)))
```

Here is another candidate for the `dist` function that might be easier to understand:

```
(defn dist [a b]
  (let [d (euclidean-dist a b)]
    (if (zero? d)
      -100
      d)))
```

Here, we simply return a large negative distance whenever there is an exact match, to strongly prefer that assignment.

Comment: Thanks, I included it in the project.clj but in the ns `(:require [munkres])` gives a syntax error `munkres - failed: #{:refer-clojure} at: [:ns-clauses :refer-clojure :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer-clojure` not sure what that means?

Comment: @user3710760 Not sure why you get this error. Have you made sure that your namespace name in ns matches that of the path to your clj file? And did you restart the REPL after adding the demendency?

Comment: Ah, sorry that was a problem on my side. It worked, great thank you so much!

Comment: Can I ask why you are reversing the order if b has less elements than a?

Comment: Did you try replacing `(< (count b) (count a))` by `false` and what results did you get? Were they still correct?

Comment: Yes, I noticed it'd not return the correct sequence, but after drawing it out now it seems like it returns the opposite i.e. the ones with the furthest distance? Btw, I tried it with the following `(def sample-set-a #{[0.575 0.675] [0.575 0.575]})` and `(def sample-set-b #{[0.575 0.675] [0.575 9.575]})` and I'd expect the first two points to be matched as they are the exact same ones but it returns: `{:assignments {[0.575 0.575] [0.575 0.675], [0.575 0.675] [0.575 9.575]}, :weight 8.999999999999998}`
I reckon it's to do with the library, but could you advise?

Comment: As far as I can tell the library does what it is supposed to do: It minimizes the objective function which is the sum of distances. In this case, did you evaluate the objective function for each of the two possible assignments to see which assignment results in a lower objective function value? Maybe that will explain things.

Comment: Regarding the issue with reversing if b has fewer elements than a, it seems like that is necessary for the algorithm to work but I cannot tell why. I suggest you do the research yourself by looking at the source code that I linked to.

Comment: I guess for my example there are two possibilities and both give the same weight, it seems to default to one only even when changing the order of the points in sample-set-b. I'll look into the source code, thanks!

Comment: I have another requirement (but let me know if i should create a new question for this): After the assignments have been made, I want to extract those that have a weight of less than some threshold maxW. I'd need to use the cost-matrix for this and look up values in :assignments, but since the matrix doesn't have column/row labels, does it mean I have to look up the index of each assignment then using that for the cost-matrix?

Comment: Assuming that `results` contains the result map with the `:assignments` key and `maxW` holds the threshold, you can get the assignments with a weight less than `maxW` with the expression `(filter #(< (apply dist %) maxW) (:assignments results))`.